# Storing constant string literals in a container

Tags: c++, string, containers, c++17, string-literals

I've got a struct `foo bar` of the form `struct foo { const char* s, ... };` and a `std::vector<foo> v;` and I want to `push_back` a few `foo`'s with constant values for the `s` member field, i.e.

```
bar.push_back({ "1", /*...*/ });
bar.push_back({ "2", /*...*/ });
bar.push_back({ "3", /*...*/ });
//...
```

Now, if I'm not totally wrong, this isn't safe, since the life time of the string literals are bounded to the scope of the initializer braces. So, the life time of the string literal `"1"` should have already been ended at the line of the second `push_back`.

How can we deal with this? Do we really need to create a second container strong `std::string`'s and passing the corresponding `c_str()` pointers to `bar`?

Comment: "life time of the string literals are bounded" no, it is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is safe as long as you only ever initialize the `const char *s` with *string literals* . They have a lifetime that is identical to the lifetime of your program.

Answer (score 1):

The way to think of string literals is as if they were const pointers to const chars.
In fact if you initialize two variables with the same string literal, they will actually point to the same address in most compiler implementations.

You can verify this by printing out the const char* pointers after casting them to integer.

Hence there is no question of "lifetime" of string literals anymore than the constant 99 has a lifetime.

They are literally literals